# Python - read_csv() does not remove the comment

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm not sure that this question is available but I have a big problem.

I have several .csv files and they have some comments line on the top with '#'.

To handle the data files, I am trying to do this:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv(file, header = None, comment='#')
```

Some files worked well but others didn't

Some comments are removed but others are not. So the dataframe is messy.

I don't know why this happen.
How can I solve it?  Should I upload the weird files?

---

**Edit**

I found the difference between the removable comment and unremovable comment.

If the comment has any comma, it is not removed. Why this happened?

```
# This comment is removed
# This comment is removed.
# This comment is not removed,
# ,This comment is not removed
# This comment is, not removed
User,Age,Gender
user1,22,female
user2,30,male
user3,25,male
user4,23,female
```

And the data frame is :

```
0  # This comment is not removed,  NaN     NaN
1  # ,This comment is not removed  NaN     NaN
2  # This comment is, not removed  NaN     NaN
3                            User  Age  Gender
4                           user1   22  female
5                           user2   30    male
6                           user3   25    male
7                           user4   23  female
```

Comment: Are you able to narrow down the "some files worked well but others didn't"? What differences can you see between them that'd give a hint as to what's going on?

Comment: @JonClements I found it!! If the comment has any comma, it is not removed!! why this happened??

Comment: I reproduced it with a comma in the comments:  `# user id , userid `. It works. Is this your use case?

Comment: @Mokshyam I tried with '# user id , userid.' and it didn't work. I am still testing with comma and without comma and it is the only problem.

Comment: Edit the question with the exact csv that is not parsing.

Comment: I suggest you read this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Are you sure without giving a separator, you were able to parse this csv. Your separator is definitely not a comma. Try this:  `dataframe = pd.read_csv(file, header = None, comment='#', sep='\s+')` Look at @GSazheniuk doc link.

Comment: @GSazheniuk Thank you for the information. I am reading it.

Comment: @Mokshyam Oop. I am really sorry. Actually, the separator is comma. I will edit the question right now.

Comment: @BingbongKim, what is your Pandas version? I can't reproduce it using `Pandas 0.20.3`. `pd.read_csv(filename, comment='#')` - works just fine

Comment: @Mokshyam I solved my problem. All comments that is containing the comma has Quotes... I couldn't see it in python prompt and LibreOffice.
I don't know why but only comma containg comments has quotes. Please forgive my stupidity.

Comment: @MaxU Thank you for commenting. It was just my fault.

Comment: @BingbongKim because it was a single column, and since it contained commas, you enclose the column itself in quotes when it's saved as CSV so the field isn't seen as multiple columns eg: a row of `1,2,3` is three columns and `"1,2,3"` is a single column.... ergo, a column of `# 1` is fine, but a column of `# 1, 2` becomes `"# 1, 2"` to preserve the comma and ensure it's considered a single column

Comment: @JonClements That is the point. How can I keep the comma containg comment without the quotes?

Comment: Well, it depends, have you loaded it into something, then saved back over it and let it do what it wants in regards to that? Do you have CSV files that are properly formatted you can use? Can you read from the document directly using `read_excel` instead of `read_csv` etc...

Comment: @JonClements Actually, the csv file is a customer's private file and I receive it from the customer. All data columns of the each csv files are same but the comments part are different. Each file has different rows of comment. I think the csv file must have been opend at least once before I receive it.

Comment: @JonClements And I have never used read_excel. Can it be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

All comments that is containing the comma has Quotes...

I couldn't see it in python prompt and LibreOffice. I don't know why but only comma containg comments has quotes.

Please forgive my stupidity.